# Php cs fixer. Indentation inside PHP tags

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

Is there a way to indent the content inside the PHP tags?

from

```
<?php

$foo = 'bar';
```

to

```
<?php

   $foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: Yea, you set your editor to `tab=4 spaces` and you tab them all when you are coding

Comment: It's not really standard. You should have a look how to implement custom standards in PHPCS here : https://ncona.com/2012/12/creating-your-own-phpcs-standard/.

But I'm wondering what is the value of that standard?

Comment: None, really. Just matter of preference! :D